# How to select unselected text along with selected text in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on an application which requires to select next line along with the selected line.

Following code is used for text selection

```
function getSelectedText() {
        var text = "";
        if (typeof window.getSelection != "undefined") {
            text = window.getSelection().toString();
        } else if (typeof document.selection != "undefined" && document.selection.type == "Text") {
            text = document.selection.createRange().text;
        }

        //        alert('text = ' + text);
        return text;
    }
```

How  to select next line of text along with selected line in javascript ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might help you to get some idea on how to achieve that:

HTML:

```
<body>

<pre>  
     Hahahaa. Jacko. Superman. Hulk.
     </pre>



 </body>
```

Javascript with JQuery:

```
function getSelectionTextWithNext() {
    var text = "";

    if (window.getSelection) {
        text = window.getSelection().toString();
    } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
        text = document.selection.createRange().text;
    }
    var preText = $("pre").text();
    var theBeginningTextIndex = preText.indexOf(text) + text.length;
    var preTextIndex = preText.indexOf('.', theBeginningTextIndex);
    var nextSentence = preText.substring(preText.indexOf(text), preTextIndex + 1);
    console.log(nextSentence);

    return nextSentence;
}
$(document).ready(function (){
   $('pre').mouseup(function (e){
       getSelectionTextWithNext();
   })
});
```

Live Demo:

```js
function getSelectionTextWithNext() {
  var text = "";

  if (window.getSelection) {
    text = window.getSelection().toString();
  } else if (document.selection && document.selection.type != "Control") {
    text = document.selection.createRange().text;
  }
  var preText = $("pre").text();
  var theBeginningTextIndex = preText.indexOf(text) + text.length;
  var preTextIndex = preText.indexOf('.', theBeginningTextIndex);
  var nextSentence = preText.substring(preText.indexOf(text), preTextIndex + 1);
  console.log(nextSentence);

  return nextSentence;
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('pre').mouseup(function(e) {
    getSelectionTextWithNext();
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>

  <pre>  
    Hahahaa. Jacko. Superman. Hulk.
    </pre>



</body>
```

The sample would find "." as the mark of the end of sentences.
The sample also might be buggy, but hopefully it gives you the ideas.

Pseudo Codes:

> 1. Get the selection text.
> 2. Go through the original text contained in the html element and use custom made logic to get the next sentence. (In this example, "." is
>      the mark of the end of sentences).

FYI,
The code posted is an extended version of

```
http://jsfiddle.net/abdennour/BQSJ3/6/
```

Tribute for the original creator.

Hope it helps.
Thanks